# Object.respond_to? stuck in infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stack-overflow, method-missing, respond-to

I'm building a Rails 3 gem that essentially modifies the records returned from an ActiveRecord query.  One of the things I'm doing is overriding the `method_missing` and `respond_to?` methods, but it seems that my `respond_to?` definition is resulting in an infinite loop that is throwing a "SystemStackError: stack level too deep" error.

Here are my original definitions of these methods:

```
def respond_to?(name, *args)
  super(name, *args) || parent_association.respond_to?(name)
end

def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  if parent_association.respond_to?(name)
    parent_association.send(name, *args, &block)
  else
    super(name, *args, &block)
  end
end

def parent_association
  send(parent_association_name)  # Essentially yields another ActiveRecord
                                 # instance (e.g.: instance of User), but
                                 # never returns itself.
end
```

In trying to learn why this infinite loop was occurring, I restructured `respond_to?` with some "before" and "after" output to see where it's getting stuck.

```
def respond_to?(name, *args)
  return true if super(name, *args)
  puts "before (#{name})"
  result = parent_association.respond_to?(name)
  puts "after"
  result
end
```

When running, it appears that various callbacks and attribute methods run as expected, with a single before and after call for each:

```
before (_run__374051839217347232__initialize__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
after
before (_run__374051839217347232__validation__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
after
before (_run__374051839217347232__validate__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
after
before (_run__374051839217347232__save__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
after
before (_run__374051839217347232__create__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
after
before (created_at)
after
before (created_on)
after
...
```

However, any time I see a find callback, that appears to be caught in an infinite loop:

```
before (_run__374051839217347232__find__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
before (_run__374051839217347232__find__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
before (_run__374051839217347232__find__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
before (_run__374051839217347232__find__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
before (_run__374051839217347232__find__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
before (_run__374051839217347232__find__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
before (_run__374051839217347232__find__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
before (_run__374051839217347232__find__1707831318230746190__callbacks)
...
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

If I hack my `respond_to?`, then everything appears to run smoothly:

```
def respond_to?(name, *args)
  return true if super(name, *args)
  return false if name =~ /^_run_.*_find_.*_callbacks$/
  parent_association.respond_to?(name)
end
```

What am I doing wrong that I seem to need this hack?  And how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being this function:

```
def parent_association
  send(parent_association_name)  # Essentially yields another ActiveRecord
                                 # instance (e.g.: instance of User), but
                                 # never returns itself.
end
```

The variable `parent_association_name` is something like `employee`, which is defined via something like:

```
belongs_to :employee
```

Because `employee` is not defined on the model instance until AFTER the find callback executes, and because I was first calling `respond_to?` in a spot BEFORE the find callback is being called (in code no included in my original question), the call to `send(parent_assocation_name)` was causing a recursive call to `respond_to?`.

Comment: It would be clearer if you used precise language. `parent_association_name` is not a variable, and I think `employee` is   always defined, although it might not be loaded. Not sure you actually mean "callback" either. I'm still not sure how what you are describing is not what I was saying, nor how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If `parent_association` returns a new AR object, it will also inherits your hack, so calling `respond_to?` on it will call your `respond_to?`, which will create a AR new object, etc...

Comment: That's not true if the other ActiveRecord object that it creates actually implements the method, which should be the case here.  For example, the other AR object will have a method like `.name` (due to the attributes implemented), which the original AR object might not have had.  At some point, it's just going to call `super` and return since the method is actually defined on the object.

Comment: Just to follow up, it did end up being recursion via `respond_to?`, but it wasn't an issue of the function being called being undefined recursively on separate AR objects, as you mentioned.